# Looking for integral-free DSP textbooks

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for a treatment of fundamental DSP theory where only discrete/finite signal models are used. To make a concrete example, every time standard textbooks write a convolution as a continuous integral, I would like to see instead a product between a Toeplitz matrix and a vector. It seems to me that developing such a theory from linear algebra would make implementing concrete DSP algorithm much easier. Think also of multirate/filter banks, etc... Except maybe for the book of Strang on Wavelets I have not seen any other book based this approach. Any book titles I have missed?

Answer (score 6):

I would like to recommend a great book to you (see below), but before that I would like to point out that there is some confusion in your question. If you see a convolution integral in a textbook, then this refers to the convolution of two continuous time signals, which can't be represented by a matrix/vector multiplication. You must be referring to the convolution of two sequences (discrete-time signals), but this convolution is always written as an infinite sum (and not as an integral). For finite length sequences, this sum can indeed be written as a (finite) matrix/vector product.

The book I was referring to is the excellent (and free!) book *[Foundations of Signal Processing](http://www.fourierandwavelets.org/FSP_v1.1_2014.pdf)* by Vetterli et al. It also stresses (among many other things) the matrix view of linear operators on sequences. I'm especially referring to chapter 3 ('sequences and discrete-time systems'), but I would actually recommend to read the whole book if you want a thorough and modern treatment of signal processing. Disclaimer: the book is not integral-free, but this shouldn't put you off, just give it a try.