# What is the best book on Digital Signal processing for math majors?

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, source-separation

I am a math major and have knowledge of Calculus, Real and Complex Analysis,PDEs and probability theory. I would like to get started with DSP and need a book suitable for math majors. Please give your suggestions. Thank you! :)

Comment: Also have a look at [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18327/looking-for-integral-free-dsp-textbooks/18328#18328).

Comment: my opinion is still [O&S](http://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Time-Signal-Processing-Edition-Prentice/dp/0131988425).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I agree with you in 100%! Oppenheim is now even doing the [online course](https://www.edx.org/course/discrete-time-signal-processing-mitx-6-341x#.VNKcEZ1z2VE).