# Signals and systems book with linear algebra approach

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, reference-request, linear-algebra, books

I am currently taking a course on discrete-time signals and systems. I am using B. P. Lathi's *Signal Processing and Linear Systems*, which I don't like at all, as it doesn't draw any paralells to linear algebra. The concept of eigenvalues and eigenvectors in linear transformation is never discussed, for example.

Can you please recommend a book on signals and systems with a linear algebra approach?

Comment: [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/18328/4298) might be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not particularly current, my junior level signals and systems text was

> Lathi, Bhagwal. Signal, Systems, and Controls. Intext, 1973

which had a some linear algebra, primarily because it had a control engineering bent.  The last chapter on mixed continuous-discrete systems was a lot to digest. I have come to appreciate it more over the years.

I used an older version of Chen in graduate school and it is very much from a linear algebra perspective, but is not aimed at the same audience Lathi is.

> Chen, Chi-Tsong. Linear system theory and design. Oxford University
>   Press, Inc., 1998.

Kailath is a bit harder than Lathi,

> Kailath, Thomas. Linear systems. Vol. 156. Englewood Cliffs, NJ:
>   Prentice-Hall, 1980.

and Luenberberger is very readable.

> Luenberger, David G. Introduction to dynamic systems: theory, models,
>   and applications. Vol. 1. New York: Wiley, 1979.

In signal processing,

> Oppenheim, Alan V., and Ronald W. Schafer. Discrete-time signal processing: Pearson new International Edition. Pearson Higher Ed,
>   2013.

Is sort of the "standard" text book on signal processing but light on linear algebra.

Strang is good but assumes you have some linear systems background.

> Strang, Gilbert, and Truong Nguyen. Wavelets and filter banks. SIAM,
>   1996.

and his book on Linear Algebra is a very good introduction.

Its hard to recommend a book without knowing your back ground, but If I were to ask the same question you did,  I would go with Chen.